# Create clickable objects with helix toolkit

Tags: c#, wpf, helix-3d-toolkit

I found on the Helix Toolkit an example, which is called to ScatterPlot, which is really close what I really need. But I can't find anything about how can I add something onclick event listener to the created objects (in this case to the sphere). This adds the sphere to the 'playground'.

```
scatterMeshBuilder.AddSphere(Points[i], SphereSize, 4, 4);
```

The basic goal is to add every sphere an onclick event listener and when the user choose a color and click one of these spheres it will change to the selected color. It's possible to add onclick listener (or something equal with it) to the spheres.

Answer (score 7):

One year later... Maybe someone will find this usefull.

A solution that worked for me revolves around extending the [UIElement3D](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement3d(v=vs.110).aspx) class, this has a bunch of standard events that you can override. e.g MouseEnter,MouseClick etc.
Source below.

```
using System.Windows; 
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Controls;

public class InteractivePoint : UIElement3D   
{
    public InteractivePoint(Point3D center, Material material, double sphereSize = 0.07)
    {
       MeshBuilder builder  = new MeshBuilder();

       builder.AddSphere( center, sphereSize , 4, 4 );
       GeometryModel3D model = new GeometryModel3D( builder.ToMesh(), material );
        Visual3DModel = model;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseEnter( MouseEventArgs event )
    {
        base.OnMouseEnter( event );

        GeometryModel3D point = Visual3DModel as GeometryModel3D;

        point.Material = Materials.Red; //change mat to red on mouse enter
        Event.Handled = true;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeave( MouseEventArgs event )
    {
        base.OnMouseEnter( event );

        GeometryModel3D point = Visual3DModel as GeometryModel3D;

        point.Material = Materials.Blue; //change mat to blue on mouse leave
        Event.Handled = true;
    }


}
```

To add them to the playground

```
Point3D[,] dataPoints = new Point3D[10,10]; // i will assume this has already been populated.
ContainerUIElement3D container;
Material defaultMaterial = Materaials.Blue;
for (int x = 0;x < 10; x++)
{
    for(int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
    {
        Point3D position = dataPoints [x, y];
        InteractivePoint  interactivePoint = new InteractivePoint( position, defaultMaterial );
        container.Children.Add( interactivePoint );
    }
}
```

Finally add the container as a child to a ModelVisual3D object.